# PHP extension check error 2.1.5?

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, php-7, linux

Hello friends,

I am new to `Magento` and I'm trying to install `Magento-2.1.5` on `Ubuntu-16.04`. While installing I'm getting an error in `php extention check`, 
error is :

> PHP Extensions Check 3 missing PHP extensions. Hide detail
>
> The best way to resolve this is to install the correct missing
>   extensions. The exact fix depends on our server, your host, and other
>   system variables.  Our PHP extension help can get you started.

[image: PHP extension error img]

For this error I'm added :

```
extension=php_bz2.dll

extension=php_curl.dll

extension=php_intl.dll

extension=php_mysqli.dll

extension=php_openssl.dll

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

This code is in `php.ini` and added that file into root folder of my application, 
but error not resolve. Please any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check permissions for newly created file "php.ini"

Comment: if you have already un-comments those lines from php.ini and enable that extension then you need to restart php fpm again run this command - `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

Comment: @ManthanDave   when i run this command it shows me the given error  faild to restart php7.0-fpm.service: unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.

Comment: @SantoshBhagwat run `php -v` command and check which version of php you have installed then run fpm command by passing that version for  the same

Comment: Just check your phpinfo to see you phpini location, then open that file in terminal using VI editor or any one. Then check and enable all of these required dependency of php after that restart Apache.

Comment: you dont undertand the difference between LINUX stack and WINDOWS stack - what are you doing there???  linux php extension is `.so` not  `.dll`

Comment: @all: if you vote to close this question as duplicate, please upvote that other question. This question has 2 upvotes and the other 0, while apparently the other is of good value, because others also have this problem (and posting duplicate questions about it).

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps.

1. Create **info.php** file in your Magento2 root directory and put
   following code in it.

   ```
   <?php
   phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
2. Now run this file in browser and find path for **Loaded Configuraton
   File**.
3. Enable given three extensions in it by removing comment.
4. Restart apache server and try again.